# How do I permanently change a shortcut's target path with perl script?

Tags: perl

I am currently trying to figure out perl's [`Win32::Shortcut`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32%3a%3aShortcut) module, and how to change shortcut paths with said module. This is for a personal project and I plan to manage shortcuts with this script

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use Win32::Shortcut;
use strict;

my $LINK;

$LINK = new Win32::Shortcut();
$LINK->Load("C:\\Users\\Jimbo\\Desktop\\VLC media player.lnk");
$LINK->{'Path'} = "http://www.google.com//";

$LINK->Save();
$LINK->Close();
```

The script runs without an issue, but when I click on the shortcut I loaded it opens VLC media player instead of google.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may appear to succeed but you didn't include any error checking. Try this:

```
$LINK->Load("C:\\Users\\Jimbo\\Desktop\\VLC media player.lnk") or die "$! ($^E)";
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry to inconvenience you, I'm just picking up perl.

Answer (score 2):

You should add error checking to every step of your program:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use Win32::Shortcut;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $link = new Win32::Shortcut();
$link->Load("C:\\Users\\Public\\Desktop\\test.lnk") or die "$! ($^E)";

$link->{'Path'} = "http://www.google.com//";

$link->Save() or die "$! ($^E)";
$link->Close() or die "$! ($^E)";
```

In the above example, I was able to find the link on my Public Desktop instead of my user one, but then it failed again because of permission: `No such file or directory (Access is denied)`.